# javascript: form length validation

Tags: javascript

I think, I got a validation problem on my javascript. It still submits while the form is invalid. Specifically, when user inputs more than 10 character in length, it still submits the form into database, while it should display alert. Here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;
var a=document.forms["purchaseform"]["no"].value;
var b=document.forms["purchaseform"]["qty"].value;
if (a==null || a=="")
  {
  alert("Form number must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if(a.match(numericExpression))
  {
  return true;
  }
  else
  {
  alert("Form number must be filled with numbers only");
  return false;
  }
if(a.length > 10) //i got a problem with this one i think
  {
  alert("Form number must not be greater than 10 character length");
  return false;
  }
if (b==null || b=="")
  {
  alert("Quantity must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if(b.match(numericExpression))
  {
  return true;
  }
  else
  {
  alert("Quantity must be filled with numbers only");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

And here is the form snippet:

```
<form name="purchaseform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="submitpurchaseadmin.php">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Form number</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="no"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>
        <select id="cat" name="cat">
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item</td>
        <td>
        <select id="item" name="item">
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo date("d-m-Y"); ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: what does `console.log(a)` display?

Comment: using document.write syntax?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an ID to those inputs and do

```
function validateForm() {
    var a = document.getElementById("no").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("qty").value;

    if (!a.length) {
        alert("Form number must be filled out");
        return false;
    }else if (!a.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
        alert("Form number must be filled with numbers only");
        return false;
    }else if (a.length > 10) {
        alert("Form number must not be greater than 10 character length");
        return false;
    }else if (!b.length) {
        alert("Quantity must be filled out");
        return false;
    }else if (!b.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
        alert("Quantity must be filled with numbers only");
        return false;
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcHDT/)

Comment: thanks, it validated correctly. may i ask what's the difference between using var a=document.forms["purchaseform"]["no"].value; and var a = document.getElementById("no").value;?

Comment: Using the global namespace to access elements just seems like a bad idea to me, but that's not really where the issue was, the issue was the way the if / else was setup, and especially when matching the numbers regex, as noted by Leo, the `if (match(regex)) else {...` always returns from the function, so the rest of it never executes.

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit` doesn't automatically prevent the form from submitting, you need to use `preventDefault` inside your onsubmit function.

See here:

[onsubmit method doesn't stop submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623244/onsubmit-method-doesnt-stop-submit)

Of note – while Adeneo's fix addresses blank name and quanity, it does not seem to be alerting on the length of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is here: `if(a.match(numericExpression))`, when user inputs more than 10 character in length, this if statement will also return true.