# Submit not calling JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, submit, onsubmit

Upon clicking submit, the function doesn't seem to get called and the form submits even if the return is false.

```
    function validateForm() {
        if (document.getElementById("nm").value="")  {
            alert("You must enter a name!"); 
            return false;
        }
        if (document.getElementById("em").value="")  {
            alert("email required"); 
            return false;
        }
    return true;
    }
```

And the HTML:

```
    <form onsubmit=" return validateForm();" action="myscript.php" id="primary">
        <label>Name<input type="text" id="nm"></input></label>
        <label>Email<input type="text" id="em"></input></label>
        <input type="submit" id="send" value="submit"></input>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `==` or `===` (exact equal to) to compare values, the `=` operator is used to assign values.

```
 function validateForm() {
    if (document.getElementById("nm").value == "")  {
        alert("You must enter a name!"); 
        return false; 
    }

    if (document.getElementById("em").value == "")  {
        alert("email required"); 
        return false; 
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Instead of `return false`, you need to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

When making a condition on an `if` statement the "is equal to" comparison symbol is `==` or `===`. `=` is used for assigning variables.

Answer (score 0):

There's already an answer for that here -> [onsubmit method doesn't stop submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623244/onsubmit-method-doesnt-stop-submit)

Basically you need to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form submission.