# simple javascript validation in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, validation

I have very very stupid bug in javascript validation

let me i explain in code :

this is my form tag

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
   <textarea id="content"   name="Body"><%= Model.Body %></textarea>
</form>
```

and this is my script :

```
 function validateForm(e) {
        debugger;
         var reviewMessage = $("[name='Body']").attr('value');
        //var overallValue = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox overall icon-checkbox').prop.checked;
        if (reviewMessage.length < 100) {
            e.preventDefault();

           // $("Body").show();
            $('#bodyValidation').css({'display' : 'block'});
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

my problem is that when ever i click the button page will be submited ;

but i want to stop this action with javascript .

how can i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623244/onsubmit-method-doesnt-stop-submit

Comment: Why don't you create `jsfiddle` of the problem?

Comment: @tushar im sorry but imot familiar with that

Comment: @salar Go to jsfiddle.net Add code in respective blocks, make sure it runs properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong.

Change

```
var reviewMessage = $("Body").val();
```

to

```
var reviewMessage = $("[name='Body']").val();

OR

var reviewMessage = $('#content').val();
```

Comment: is it the main problem of submiting page ?

Comment: @salar Yes, because you've `preventDefault()` and `return false` both in the condition that is using this value

Comment: @salar If you look at your own code, you'll realize that if the length of `Body`'s value is shorter than 100, you'll do the validation, otherwise you simply submit.

Comment: @JeffNoel I update my code but still the same problem

Comment: @salar You need to help us to help you. We're *guessing* what the `Body` element is, please include it in your code. Which browser are you testing your code in? If it is IE, `event.preventDefault()` will not work and you will need to use `event.returnValue = false` instead. Try debugging your code using the console and developper tools integrated within your browser.

Comment: @JeffNoel The condition is ok but my main problem is that page will be submited